# Very fast video capture (vs AVCaptureMovieFileOutput)?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm working on a video capture app similar to Vine or Instagram. This lets the user hold down to record, release touch to pause, and continue again by touching.

I have my prototype working, I'm capturing the video, merging them and cropping them fine. I'm using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

On touch down, I start recording:

```
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

On touch up, I stop:

```
[MovieFileOutput stopRecording];
```

Problem: By my logs, it seems it takes at least `0.054` seconds after touch down until recording actually begins. This mean very quick taps lasting about `0.050` seconds will not be captured because `MovieFileOutput` will be told to `stopRecording` before it actually ever gets started. It may seem insignificant, but Vine is able to capture and record these taps.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: maybe start a timer on touch down with `NSDate`. Then put an If statement around stopRecording. check if `timeIntervalSinceNow` is smaller than x time. If it is, set an `NSTimer` to wait for x time - `timeIntervalSinceNow`, then stop recording.

Comment: another thought : broadcasting camera's have the option to buffer. They are always recording but only keep the last x frames. unless record was pressed. then it saves the buffered frames and everything new until recording is stopped. If you could implement that, you could make it as fast as you like.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  Thanks for the help!